# Simple Vue component not rendering

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to learn Vue.JS, and the component I have made is not rendering on the page. This is my component:

```
import Vue from 'vue'

const card = new Vue({
  el: '#card',
  data: {
    title: 'Dinosaurs',
    content: '<strong>Dinosaurs</strong> are a diverse group of animals 
from the clade <em>Dinosauria</em> that first appeared at the Triassic 
period.'
  }
})
```

This is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Vue Practice</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="card">
      <header>{{ title }}</header>
      <div v-html="content"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And this is package.json (I realize most of the dependencies belong in devDependencies):

```
    {
      "name": "vue-practice",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "",
      "main": "index.js",
      "scripts": {
        "bundle": "browserify -t babelify -t vueify -e main.js > 
                   bundle.js",
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
      },
      "keywords": [],
      "author": "",
      "license": "ISC",
      "dependencies": {
        "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs": "^6.26.0",
        "babelify": "^7.3.0",
        "browserify": "^14.4.0",
        "vue": "^2.4.2",
        "vueify": "^9.4.1"
      },
      "devDependencies": {}
    }
```

When I load index.html in the browser, all it renders is {{ title }} and I am receiving no errors. Any explanation as to why this is happening would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you using the Vue+Compiler package? Post your `package.json`.

Comment: I thought vueify would do the job, but I'll post the entire package.json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vueify` only transforms `*.vue` files, **if you are going to use templating in your `index.html` then you need Vue compiler** in order to compile the template in the browser (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Runtime-Compiler-vs-Runtime-only).

A good way to have things like that covered is to use a `vuejs-template`, if you are using Browserify there is one: https://github.com/vuejs-templates/browserify

But as you have almost everything up, you can only add what's missing for the compiler package, as stated in "Runtime + Compiler vs. Runtime-only" - "Browserify" section in Vue guide.

**Add to your `package.json`**:

```
{
    "browser": {
        "vue": "vue/dist/vue.common.js"
    },
}
```

That will tell Browserify to use the full (also called standalone) Vue build on browser.

---

Another way is to not use templates in `index.html` but instead in a main component, like `App.vue`, for that you check out the template I linked above, it does it out of the box.